# MySQL FULL TEXT SEARCH only filter matched word contains results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm writing  a full text query that kind for  a search functionally.
It need to get results if that only contain matched word,
Ex-

product names -

1st product- inkjet epson printer 1158,

2nd product- inkjet hp printer 2250

if the user search **inject printer** it should **show both**

**inkjet epson printer 1158,inkjet hp printer 2250**

if the user search **inkjet epson** it should **show one**

**inkjet epson printer 1158****

if the user search **hp printer** it should **show one**

**inkjet hp printer 2250**

i used + operator for that

ex

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(pro_name) AGAINST('+inkjet +epson ')
SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(pro_name) AGAINST('+hp +printer')
```

but i getting both products for the results, can anyone help me with this.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(pro_name) AGAINST('+inkjet* +epson*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR

SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(pro_name) AGAINST('+inkjet +epson' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(pro_name) AGAINST('+hp* +printer*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR

SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(pro_name) AGAINST('+hp +printer' IN BOOLEAN MODE)